# A method or function that returns a list of pairs of numbers which would sum up to 5

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a function in JAVA which would give me a List of Pairs of Numbers.

This pair of numbers which would add up to 5, so ultimate goal is to print this list of pair of numbers

I have this code to determine pair but not sure how to return from method.
Please Note: **I have used void as I have no clue of how to return values from method in the form {(numberA[0], numberB[0]), (numberA[1], numberB[1]), ....}?**

```
public void setNumberList(int[] numberList) {

    ArrayList<Integer> numberA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numberB = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {

        int first = numberList[i];

        for (int j = i + 1; j < numberList.length; j++) {

            int second = numberList[j];

            if ((first + second) == 5) {

                numberA.add(first);
                numberB.add(second);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code you already have and specify where you are having trouble. Stop by the [help] and read [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing there must also be other limits, otherwise this question has an infinite number of solutions. `-23 + 28`, as just one example.

Comment: You have the numbers in your lists `numberA` and `numberB`. Please edit your question with the problem you have right now, you have not asked any question.

Comment: how to return values from method in the form {(numberA[0], numberB[0]), (numberA[1], numberB[1]), ....}

Comment: @BVK0118 You can change the return type to `Set<List<Integer>>`. And return a `Set` with lists of numbers (which will have only 2 elements each) which sum results in your search number `5`.

Comment: @Progman Would really appreciate if you could give an example!

Comment: The question is locked until the question has been improved and has been reviewed by other users, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions. Until then no answers can be added. Please edit your question to include your solutions to return the data from your method, but didn't work. For each solution you tried, add the full source code you used and the error messages you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the return type of your method to `Set<List<Integer>>`. The `Set` will contain lists of numbers, where the numbers in each list will sum up to your target number `5`. The method will look like this:

```
public static Set<List<Integer>> setNumberList(int[] numberList) {

    ArrayList<Integer> numberA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numberB = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {

        int first = numberList[i];

        for (int j = i + 1; j < numberList.length; j++) {

            int second = numberList[j];

            if ((first + second) == 5) {

                numberA.add(first);
                numberB.add(second);
            }
        }
    }
    Set<List<Integer>> result = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();
    for (int i=0; i<numberA.size(); i++) {
        int n1 = numberA.get(i);
        int n2 = numberB.get(i);
        List<Integer> numbersToAdd = Arrays.asList(n1, n2);
        result.add(numbersToAdd);
    }
    return result;
}
```